# OpenVZ - SMTP - telnet - Connection timed out

Tags: iptables, postfix, smtp, openvz, telnet

I have problem with SMTP in my OpenVZ container.

I've created OpenVZ container by Proxmox on dedicated server in OVH. This container will be as mail server. So I create on "mother-server" rules to pass ports to container (IP: 192.168.0.100):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:25
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:587
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 110 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:110
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:143
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 995 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:995
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:993
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I can receive mails but I can't send. I can send only to local domain - for test I use calcparty.com .

In /etc/postfix/main.cf I've set:

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

I can make telnet localhost 25 but I can't make telnet smtp.gmail.com .
From "mother-server" I can make telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 .

What do I do wrong ?

```
root@mail:~# telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Trying 64.233.166.108...
Trying 64.233.166.109...
Trying 2a00:1450:400c:c09::6d...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

File - /etc/resolv.conf :

```
search mail.calcparty.com
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 213.186.33.99
```

Answer (score 1):

The masquerade rule is wrong:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

It is saying that packets going *out* the vmbr0 interface and *from* 192.168.0.0/24 should be masqueraded.

But no packets will ever match this, because they aren't going *out* the vmbr0 interface! Instead they are going out your *physical* interface.

Change this to refer to packets going out the physical interface instead, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o enp3s0f0 -j MASQUERADE
```